# Secure Python Markdown Library

Tags: python, security, markdown, code-injection, sanitization

I'd like to enable users to leave rich text comments, possibly using markdown. I've installed the libraries used on Reddit, but am concerned about the javascript injection attack which occurred last year, especially since I'm still not clear on the details of how the attack was done. Should I still be concerned about comment security? Is there a test string I can put through my system to check for the same flaws that took down reddit?

Answer (score 4):

[Python-Markdown](http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/) - the 'standard' one more or less - has a 'safe mode' feature that escapes html tags. That should be enough to counter most all HTML injection attacks.

Answer (score 4):

reddit uses the [discount markdown library](http://www.pell.portland.or.us/~orc/Code/discount/) now.

Comment: I'm working in a pure python environment (google app engine) so I don't think I can use a C library. I'm looking at the library Scavenger mentioned above, and also looking at the filters.py and markdown.py code from reddit. The freewisdom library is *intended* to be dropped into another project, whereas obviously you intended the reddit code to work in reddit, so that leans me toward the freewisdom code. On the other hand, I'm curious about why you needed to write your own filter code in the first place -- are there vulnerabilities in the publicly available libraries I should be aware of?

Answer (score 2):

The other answers mention Python-Markdown's safe mode but that is now deprecated. The authors of Python-Markdown have been quoted saying:

> "safe-mode" was a poor name choice that we continue to use for backward 
>   comparability (old code still works with our newer versions). What it really 
>   is is a no-markup mode. In other words, it is just a way to disallow raw html 
>   and really doesn't guarantee safety.

They now recommend using an HTML sanitizer like [Bleach](http://bleach.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to sanitize the Markdown output. [mdx_bleach](https://github.com/Wenzil/mdx_bleach) is a Python-Markdown extension that does just that. Disclaimer: I'm the author of this extension.

Because it uses html5lib to parse document fragments the same way browsers do, Bleach is extremely resilient to unknown attacks, much more so than regular-expression-based sanitizers.